# Odoo 13 Page Unresponsive Message in Views

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, odoo, odoo-13

I have a problem with my Odoo 13 community server, it started a few days ago when I tried using the "Update List" option in the Apps view, the page suddenly froze and I got a page unresponsive message so I used the command line for updating, however now I'm having the same issue when I try to open the Settings view.

My server is in an Ubuntu VM, I already checked if the RAM memory was the issue but the meminfo says it still has 2gb free.

This issue began after installing some modules I require for an extremely important project so removing them is not an option.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Disable the modules one by one to narrow down the culprit, and also check into the logs to see if any errors are being thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the running process and run the database again from terminal.

To list the running process

ps | aux grep odoo

To kill the process

sudo kill -9 process id